# Preview on editing profile looks different from actual profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, markdown-preview

When editing my profile, I noticed that `<h1>` has a bottom border and bold text (click the first image), while `<a>` has text underline.

> [image: preview]
>
> <sup>Click to see full image</sup>

But on the actual profile page, `<h1>` doesn't have a bottom border and the text isn't bold. Neither does `<a>` has text underline.

> [image: actual]

It seems like two different sets of CSS are used in preview and actual display. Should this be fixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxed?